# Are there many occurrences of elongated syllables throughout the language?

Tags: pronunciation, long-vowels

I've been studying Japanese through Duolingo and I wouldn't say I've progressed very far. I've learned some of the basics of Hiragana and it's beginning to transition into Kanji. While learning Hiragana I learned that `House` is pronounced `Ie` or `いえ`. When I began to transition into Kanji, I learned that `no` is pronounced `Īe` or `いいえ` with an elongated `I` syllable. When I translate `House` using Google Translate, a new character is presented: `家`. I would assume this is correct, as the pronunciation sounds the same to me.

---

Are there a multitude of instances where this elongation of syllables occurs forming new words?

What is a good rule of thumb for remembering such differences?

Is it difficult to differentiate in rushed conversations?

Comment: Katsura Sunshine talks about that for a minute starting 2:19 in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbt0jAYDVOw

Comment: My favorite examples include: *kokyō* "hometown" vs *kōkyo* "imperial palace", *shōjo* "girl" vs *shojo* "virgin", *bottō-suru* "to devote oneself" vs *bōtto-suru* "to be out of it".

Comment: In the digital courses I have taken, the pronounciation of いいえ is rather clear: I hear like two "i", or said otherwise the double length of a normal "i", and I would spell it more "iie" than "ie": because it IS VERY long. Really long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are there a multitude of instances where this elongation of syllables occurs forming new words?

Yes, there are thousands of word pairs whose only difference is the length of a vowel.

> Is it difficult to differentiate in rushed conversations?

Apparently *yes* for learners, but *no* for native Japanese speakers. As a native speaker of Japanese, I never thought this was difficult to distinguish even in hasty speech.

> What is a good rule of thumb for remembering such differences?

I doubt there is an easy way. You have to be aware how important this distinction is, and you have to familiarize yourself with the Japanese pronunciation system as early as possible. The Japanese language is [mora-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_(Japanese_prosody)). It may take time to understand and get used to it, but it's important. Once you've understood the general rule, this is no longer a big problem.

Seeing from the other side, native Japanese speakers have difficulty distinguishing the difference between the "r" consonant and the "l" consonant. For example, *right* and *light* sound identical to Japanese ears. Japanese students who failed to take it seriously at their initial stage of learning Engrish will actuarry keep making stlange sperring ellors rike this for many years. Learning a new language usually involves learning to recognize sounds that are not used or distinguished in your mother tongue.

Related:

- [Do native speakers think of prolonged vowels as one long vowel, or two vowel sounds following each other?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30035/5010)
- [Is it just me, or is "ryokai" pronounced "yokai" regularly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41931/5010)
- [Why do Japanese speakers have difficulty pronouncing "L"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8324/5010)

Comment: Ages ago, my wife and I were living in Tokyo and paid a visit to the Ameyokochō market.  A fellow had a small table arranged with bootleg CDs.  I _really_ wish I'd bought one -- guitar music by that well-known maestro of the modern guitar, Elic Crapton.  