# How to explain the katakana spelling for a foreign name with a long vowel?

Tags: pronunciation, katakana

Apologies in advance if the title of my question is unclear.  Please edit if you can think of a better way to phrase it!

From time to time, you need to explain how a foreign name is spelled in katakana.  Example: The first name `Bart` is commonly written as `バート`.

Imagine that you are applying for a credit card on the telephone.  What is the correct way to explain this katakana spelling?

Example: `名{な}（ファーストネーム）はバートです。バ、（？）、ト。`

How to explain that the first katanana character (`バ`) has a long vowel?

Related topic: How to explain a small vowel?  Example: `Tio` might be written as `ティオ`.  How to explain the small `イ`?  Normally, I would say `テ、小{ちい}さいイ、オ`, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: There's a name for the ー 
 in バート. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77373/what-is-the-function-of-%e4%b8%80-in-%e3%83%90%e3%82%b9%e3%83%ab%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0-and-%e3%82%b3%e3%83%b3%e3%83%94%e3%83%a5%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can pronounce バート correctly in the Japanese way, that's it. Simply elongate バ as it is actually spelled. As long as your pronunciation is clear, no one will be confused between バート and バト. (Read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65027/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73355/5010) if you have doubts.) The same for ティオ. By the way, conveying kanji over the phone can be [much trickier](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9572/5010).

If this fails and you do need to explain, you can say バは伸{の}ばします ("*Ba* is elongated").

If this fails and you do have to tell the spelling character by character, the `－` symbol is called 伸ばし【のばし】棒【ぼう】 or 長音符【ちょうおんぷ】, so you can say "カタカナでバ、伸{の}ばし棒{ぼう}、ト". For ティオ, yes, "テ、小さいイ、オ" works perfectly.

If everything above fails, there is something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_radiotelephony_alphabet) as a last resort, but I doubt you would ever need this.

Comment: Good point about kanji!  If I need to "spell" kanji, I do some research in advance to find simple words that most native Japanese speakers will know that include the specific kanji.